# Are DLC fighters such as Piranha Plant included in World of Light?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Title basically says it all. Are DLC fighters such as Piranha plant (and to be released ones like Joker) included/going to be included in World of Light? Are they on the map? Do you just have them unlocked automatically? What is the situation exactly?

Comment: Other than Piranha Plant, we won't be able to tell how the other are unlocked in World of Light until they are released or if a Nintendo staff member tells us how beforehand. Who knows they might not appear at all in WLC!

Comment: @MBorg that's a good point, I hadn't even considered that upcoming DLC fighters would be treated differently. although I still suspect they will be treated the same way (cause why not?)

Comment: I had a thought when writing that comment is that third party DLC characters may be treated differently and not be included. But more likely I agree that they’ll be in. The trigger may be harder though e.g. 20 characters, then 30, then 40 etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR: Piranha Plant is playable after 10 other characters have been unlocked in World of Light.**

When I opened World of Light (WoL) for the first time after getting Piranha Plant, I was greeted with this message:

[image: Plant Received]

And I was able to find Plant in my character selection screen:

[image: Plant in Character Select]

However, when I booted up a new WoL game, all I had was Kirby--Plant wasn't in my roster. I played the first few battles until I earned Mario (the first new character you unlock) to see if that would trigger, but unfortunately:

[image: Still No Plant]

My guess is that there's a trigger somewhere--after beating a certain amount of WoL you automagically unlock all the DLC characters you have--but I didn't play far enough on the new save state to find it.

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to @MBorg for pointing out that the trigger is [unlocking 10 characters](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Piranha_Plant_(SSBU)#Role_in_World_of_Light). As shown, in my previous game I’d already done this which is why Plant was unlocked automatically.

**Edit 2:**

Once again, @MBorg has pulled through here. It appears that [the trigger for Joker is also unlocking 10 characters](https://au.ign.com/wikis/super-smash-bros-ultimate/Joker), so it's probably safe to assume this will be the trigger for all future DLC as well.

Comment: If you start a new WoL game, the trigger is that you must unlock 10 characters before you receive Piranha Plant: https://www.ssbwiki.com/Piranha_Plant_(SSBU)#Role_in_World_of_Light

Comment: Joker has the same unlock requirements as Piranha Plant: https://au.ign.com/wikis/super-smash-bros-ultimate/Joker